# How to import correctly Bootstrap 4 in an Angularjs App that uses Bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

I am trying to migrate my App, which uses AngularJS 1.6.x and currenlty Bootstrap 3. I installed bootstrap 4, along with Popper.js and JQuery, and made a lot of the re-writing of classes for Bootstrap 3 to 4.

The thing is, the Grid doesn't seem to be imported anywhere, elements are all over the place. I mean my App needs more work to look as in Bootstrap 3, but it shouldn't be that broken.

What I want is a clear explanation, of how to correctly import Bootstrap 4, in an AngularJS Application. More specifically, what needs to be done in webpack.config.js, if I need to import it differently, if I need additional npm packages etc...

**Guys and Girls, I know this is a somewhat vague question, but there is nothing on the web, for AngularJS. So, please answer my question if you know the answer. If you don't don't report it, because many people have a similar question to this, yet no-one is answering it.**

Here is some code:

In the index.js file:

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

In the app.js file:

```
require('bootstrap');
```

In the package.json file:

```
"bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
```

Again most of the classes, and the webpack.config.js seem to be configured correctly, but I am not sure. So, if you can redirect me to  guide I would highly appreciate it. Again don't report the Q..

**UPDATE**
My file structure is fairly complicated. There are 2 apps, login and core.

```
root
 |--node_modules
 |--src
 |   |--auth
 |   |   |--login
 |   |   |    |--assets
 |   |   |    |    |--html
 |   |   |    |    |   |--index.html
 |   |   |    |    |--scss
 |   |   |    |    |   |--styles.scss
 |   |   |    |    |--index.js
 |   |--app
 |   |   |--core
 |   |   |   |--assets
 |   |   |   |    |--html
 |   |   |   |    |   |--index.html
 |   |   |   |    |--scss
 |   |   |   |    |   |--styles.scss
 |   |   |   |    |--index.js
 |   |--app.js
 |   |--app.main.js
 |   |--app.menu.js
 |   |--app.routes.js
 |   |--index.js
 |--package.json
 |--webpack-base.config.js
 |--webpack.config.js
```

This is a small sample of the file structure. There are more files but they are not important in the scope of this question.

Also, I have to tell you that I completely rewrote our Classes to use Bootstrap 4 classes. Thing is the Styles aren't getting appliead at all. Not even the CDN works.

I am at a complete loss over this. It should just work out of the box. As far as errors are concerned, I have none. The program compiles perfectly. It is broken though. No css,scss styles, nor bootstrap overrides are applied. Hope I answered your question.

As a side note, I followed the Webpack guide on Bootstrap's website [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/webpack/).

Comment: How is your folder structure? What is the error you are getting?

Comment: I added an update to your inquiry. Please check it out. Thanks for the response!

Comment: So have you checked you bundle if Bootstrap v.4 styles are there?

Comment: another question: have you checked with Developer Tools if styles _are not_ applied? they may be overrided by some other stuff(as far as I understood you have not erase Bootstrap v3 so far - can it override v4's styles?)

Comment: I have deleted Bootstrap 3 entirely(deleted bootstrap folder in node_modules). Then install bootstrap 4 fresh. So no as far as bootstrap 3 is concerned it dhouldn't override anything.

Comment: As far as the bundle goes, there are mentions to bootstrap.min.css, but it is minified so I cannot understand it very well.. Also, on the console matter, not even the css overrides we have written for bootstrap customization are getting applied. All of the styles are pure html element styles...